# Deployment Issue in Hardhat using `module.exports.tags`

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs, chainlink, hardhat-deploy

I can't seem to deploy my "deploy-mocks.js" file using `yarn hardhat deploy --tags mocks`. Here's my code if you want to take a look. I have searched everywhere but can't find the answer. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
const { network } = require("hardhat");
const { developmentChains, DECIMALS, INITAL_ANSWER } = require("../helper-hardhat-config");

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments;
    const deployer = await getNamedAccounts();
    const chainId = network.config.chainId;

    if (developmentChains.includes(chainId)) {
        log("Local Chain detected. Deploying Mocks...");
        const mockAggregator = await deploy("MockV3Aggregator", {
            contract: "MockV3Aggregator",
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [DECIMALS, INITAL_ANSWER],
        });
        log("Mocks Deployed!");
        log("---------------------------------------------------------");

        // You can perform additional deployment tasks here if needed
    }
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"];
```

Here's the output from my code.

[image: Output]

Comment: try the same thing with npx once and see if that's working.

Comment: is this line evaluating to true?
if (developmentChains.includes(chainId)) {.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked in `developmentChains.includes(chainId)` I was using chainId as a reference. However in my config.js file I defined the network properties as their names. so I changed the `developmentChains.includes(chainId)` to `developmentChains.includes(network.name)`